# bash loop for strelka2 processing for multiple files from one directory

Tags: bash

In the below `bash loop for strelka2`, 3 bam files are being stored in a variable. The two questions are:

Is this proper way to loop through multi bam and wait for workflow to be created for `strelka2` processing,
and can you create a workflow in a directory without the bam in it. Thank you :).

**contents of dir**

```
s1.bam
s2.bam
s3.bam
```

**bash**

```
dir=/path/to/bam
data=/path/to/processed/data

cd $dir
 for bam in ${dir}/*.bam; do sample_basename=$(basename "${bam}"); done # loop through dir and get bam

${path_to_strelka}/bin/configureStrelkaGermlineWorkflow.py \
  --bam ${dir}/${sample_basename} \
  --referenceFasta <fasta> \
  --runDir ${data}
  wait  # wait until workflow in data is created before executing below  in data
${data}/runWorkflow.py -m local -j 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop you're using does not work, as it overwrites the value of `sample_basename` each time. Plus, given that you're passing in the full path to the bam (using `$dir/$sample_basename`) anyway, I don't see the reason to use the `sample_basename` variable at all.

Just this:

```
dir=/path/to/bam
data=/path/to/processed/data
ref_fa=/path/to/ref/fasta

cd $dir

for bam_file in *.bam
do
  ${path_to_strelka}/bin/configureStrelkaGermlineWorkflow.py \
    --bam ${bam_file} \
    --referenceFasta ${ref_fa} \
    --runDir ${data}
  ${data}/runWorkflow.py -m local -j 20 #I'm assuming this goes inside the loop. If not, move it outside the loop. You don't need a `wait` in a shell script that's working line-by-line already.
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much :).